# Processing AI Platform Batch Results BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

The output from AI Platform for tabular dataset looks something like this: [image: bigquery screnshot]

or

```
{
"classes": ["a","b","c"],
"scores": [0.9,0.1,0.0]
}
```

There are two **arrays** within in a **record** field. predicted_label.classes is the label, and predicted_label.scores is the score produced by AI Platform.

I would like to select the **class** based on the highest **score**. i.e in the above example I would like to have an output like `row=0, class="a", score=0.9`

UNNEST does not immediately solve my issue from my understanding, as it requires the input to be an array. I believe if the ouput was a **repeated RECORD** it would be easier.

What SQL query will enable me to extract the right label from the AI Platform batch results?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
with testdata as (
  select struct(["a", "b", "c"] as classes, [0.9, 0.1, 0.0] as scores) as predicted_label
)
select (
  select struct(offset, class, score)
  from unnest(predicted_label.classes) as class with offset
  join unnest(predicted_label.scores) as score with offset
  using (offset)
  order by score desc
  limit 1
) as highest
from testdata
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You should design your prediction list so that each label and score is represented as a key-value pair.

That BigQuery table looks like this array.

```
prediction RECORD REPEATED
prediction.label STRING REQUIRED
prediction.score FLOAT REQUIRED
```

Why?

- This a correct representation of your real world situation.
- You need no further verification that both list keep the elements in the correct pairing order (on write and on read).
- With two loose lists you create a pitfall that will hounds you.

SQL example

```
with this_model as (
  select [ 
      STRUCT ('a' as label, 0.9 as score)
      , STRUCT ('b' as label, 0.1 as score)
      , STRUCT ('c' as label, 0.0 as score)
  ] as prediction
)

select pair.label, pair.score
from this_model, UNNEST(prediction) pair 
order by pair.score desc 
limit 1;
```

Comment: AI Platform outputs the results in this format, I agree it would be better if it were shaped in the way you've suggested